# Remove functions if not greater than one

Tags: jquery, function

I am using this [vTicker script](http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/). It uses an `li` to scroll the items and there are also `Previous` and `Next` buttons. I want to mod the jQuery to say if there is only one `li` do not scroll and hide the buttons.

```
<div id="scroller">
    <ul id="list">
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
        <li>Test 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a class="Prev" href="#">Prev</a>
<a class="Next" href="#">Next</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){
    var $scroller = $("#jqscroller");
    $scroller.vTicker('init', {height: 20, showItems: 1});

    $(".next").click(function(){ 
        $scroller.vTicker('next');
    });

    $(".prev, .next").hover(function(){ 
        $scroller.vTicker('pause', true);
    }, function(){
        $scroller.vTicker('pause', false);
    });

    $(".prev").click(function(){ 
        $scroller.vTicker('prev');
    });
});
```

So is there a way to only call the function if `li` is greater than 1 and add a css class to the buttons so I can `display:none` them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
if ($('#list li').length === 1) {
   $('.Prev, .Next').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var $scroller = $("#jqscroller");

    if ( $('#list li').length > 1 ) {
         $scroller.vTicker('init', {height: 20, showItems: 1});
    } else {
      $('.Prev, .Next').hide();
    }

    $(".Next").click(function(){ 
        $scroller.vTicker('next');
    });

    $(".Prev, .Next").hover(function(){ 
        $scroller.vTicker('pause', true);
    }, function(){
        $scroller.vTicker('pause', false);
    });

    $(".Prev").click(function(){ 
        $scroller.vTicker('prev');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($("#list li").length > 1) {
    $scroller.vTicker('init', {height: 20, showItems: 1});
}
else {
    $(".Prev, .Next").hide();
}
```